# What positions are there where the final actual outcome in real games contradict engine evalulation?

Tags: database

This question triggered by a position reached today round 9 in WCC 2023. According to [lichess Masters DB](https://lichess.org/analysis/rnb2rk1/1pp1qppp/5n2/pBb1p3/P3P3/2P2N2/1PQN1PPP/R1B2RK1_w_-_-_3_11?color=white) that position was reached 17 times in which black won 3 times and the rest are drawn which is interesting since this position is +0.3 according to the Engine. Understabley this is too small a sample of 17 games of which many draws; But I have to wonder, are there position that were reached 20+ time or so and DB results contradict the engine evaluation?

```
rnb2rk1/1pp1qppp/5n2/pBb1p3/P3P3/2P2N2/1PQN1PPP/R1B2RK1 w - - 3 11
```

Comment: Pretty much everything in the King's Indian

Comment: Engine at which depth? Small depths get overruled by humans all the time. But like @David said KID is the most topical example - correspondence play practice shows it's as sound as Nimzo, just engines consider it around +1 even at great depths. Most often engines overrate for white positions with space advantage - so further examples are also Benoni and French, even if both are more dubious.

Comment: The starting position? 

Answer (score -2):

Sure, here are [some examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bishop_and_knight_checkmate#Grandmasters_failing_to_mate) where the game ends drawn with the engine evaluation at MX (i.e., mate in X moves). As given by Wiki, Robert Kempinski (2498) – Vladimir Epishin (2567) [E60] Bundesliga 0001 Germany (5.3), 07.01.2001

```
[FEN "8/8/8/8/4K3/2kn4/5b2/8 w - - 0 1"]
```

Comment: This is how I imagine an AI would answer the question

Comment: I got this answer parashprased more or less when entering this into GPT 3.5